# How long does a AWS Lambda keep its execution context for a regularly executing function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I understand that lambdas re-use the execution context to avoid bootstrapping and latency cost on each invocation. As documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html).

If the lambda is used frequently (at least once a minute) is there a specific duration before the execution context is flushed and re-cached? Or is it kept in cache indefinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any hard limits Lambda kills a function if it's called regularly, though you shouldn't rely on it. A function can be killed any time and for no particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

If lambda function stays inactive for 15 minutes , then the execution context is flushed and re-cached , however you can keep it warm by invoking it every 14th minute with the help of cloudwatch events or any relevant trigger.